# Stiefel-Whitney and Wu classes of $d$-manifold

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

Is it true that Stiefel-Whitney $w_i$ and Wu classes $u_i$ of $d$-manifold, we always have the following:
$$
u_{d-1}=0, \tag{1}
$$ 
$$
u_d=0, \tag{2}
$$ 
$$
Sq^1(u_{d-1})=0. \tag{3}
$$ 
in any dimensions $d$?

- Why are the above conditions true?
- Do we have more conditions than the above in some dimensions $d$?

Comment: Note that in dimension 2 it is not necessarily true that $Sq^1(u_1) = 0$. For example, consider $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^2$. Then $u_1 = w_1$ and $w_1^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: that is a good point - how about general $d$? Do we have more conditions for generic manifolds?

Comment: For $d>2$ see Michael’s answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $M$ be a closed $d$-dimensional manifold. Recall that the Wu classes $u_i$ satisfy $\operatorname{Sq}^i(x) = u_i\cup x$ for all $x \in H^{d-i}(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$. One of the properties of Steenrod squares is that $\operatorname{Sq}^i(x) = 0$ for $i > \deg x$. In particular, for $i > d - i$ (i.e. $i > \frac{d}{2}$), we have $0 = \operatorname{Sq}^i(x) = u_i\cup x$ for all $x \in H^{d-i}(M; \mathbb{Z}_2)$. By Poincaré duality, we see that $u_i = 0$.

Comment: thanks +1, So the above criteria I listed are the all conditions for generic $d$-manifold --- are there more? (i.e. Without imposing addition structures on manifolds, such as spin, pin$^{\pm}$, etc.)

Comment: First, the conditions you wrote do not hold for all $d$ (see Aleksandar Milivojevic's comment). Second, you only wrote that the last two Wu classes vanish, my answer shows that in general there are many more which vanish.

Comment: Just to make sure, in 3d, as far as I understood before, I have $u_2=u_3=Sq^1(u_2)=0$, and in 4d, I have $u_3=u_4=Sq^1(u_3)=0$. But it looks that you wrote something different than what I thought?

Comment: For your notation, $Sq^i(x)$, I have $i=1$, but you wrote $i>d/2$. Thanks.

Comment: you wrote $i>d/2$, in contrast for my $d=3,4$ examples above.

Comment: What you wrote for $d = 3$ and $4$ is correct. But for $d > 4$, what I wrote is stronger than what you wrote in your question. For example, when $d = 5$, not only do we have $u_4 = u_5 = 0$, and hence $\operatorname{Sq}^1(u_4) = \operatorname{Sq}^1(0) = 0$, we also have $u_3 = 0$.